# Copy text button from the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have multiple records. Each record has an input with unique text prdefined and button to copy this text to clipboard. Everything works fine as long as i have only one record. In case of multiple records, only the first one seem to work. I will need help on make it work with many inputs and buttons, any advice? Another question is if is possible to hide an input (type='hidden'). I tried  but it doesn't seem to work.

My HTML:

```
<input  id='1' class="js-copytextarea" value='Sample Text to Copy 1 '>
<button  class="js-textareacopybtn" data-id="1">COPY</button>
<br>    
<input  id='2' class="js-copytextarea" value='Sample Text to Copy 2 '>
<button class="js-textareacopybtn" data-id="2">COPY</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');
copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var elem = $(this), selectedinput = elem.attr('data-id'); 
  console.log(selectedinput);
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

Link to jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/p58z0yrq/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you already attached the jQuery library to your code. So, you can use jQuery to make it easier.

```js
$('.js-textareacopybtn').on('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = $(this).data('id');
  $('#' + copyTextarea)[0].select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id='1' class="js-copytextarea" value='Sample Text to Copy 1 '>
<button  class="js-textareacopybtn" data-id="1">COPY</button>
<br>    
<input  id='2' class="js-copytextarea" value='Sample Text to Copy 2 '>
<button class="js-textareacopybtn" data-id="2">COPY</button>
```

If you are going to copy from a hidden input, I recommend to use this: https://github.com/terinjokes/zClip

Comment: works ok, the only  problem i have is to make it work with hidden input.

Comment: hmm thanks for your help but i had it tested and it dosn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/apqw5pdw/)

Comment: i tried with hiding input with css, also no success!

Comment: @Nita, Good luck buddy ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only selects one element, if you want to select all with a given class use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) then iterate through the collection and bind event handlers to them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mojtaba i solved Javascript part of my problem. I also manage to hide an input with CSS. I guess i should use zClip but for now CSS shortcut works form me.

Just add class to an input (.input-noshow)

CSS:

```
.input-noshow {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width:5px;
    color:transparent;
    cursor:default;
}
.input-noshow::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
.input-noshow::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
```